# How to make cut off kind of a circle from a div with shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

So i have a div with box shadow , the value is  "box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);" and the background color is white.
at the left you cant see there is kind of a cut off circle with a picture on it, between the circle and the big div there should be transparent background, i mean you should see through it.

on hover the cut off circle changes into kind of rectangle as you can see. and the border at the left of the div changes its radius as well as you can see.
i just cant make it happen, i thought maybe i can just get the cut off big div shape as an svg and use it as a background image but this wont be so good because on hover ill need to switch background images and i will not have an affect when the border changes it shape.
[this is regular shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYc0A.png)
[this is on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi9Q6.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your code so we can help.

Comment: the code isnt relevant here because i dont care about the stuff inside the big div, you can just asume there is a div with box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) and the background color is white i just need to know how i make this cut off shapes in a way i can show the transition between the 2 cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't like SVG, guess you could do it like this, but it want be transparent for real:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .wrapper{
        position: relative;
        margin: 2em;
      }
      .box1{
        position:relative;
        height: 6em;
        margin-left: 3em;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      }
      .box1:before{
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.5em;
        left: -2.5em;
        height: 5em;
        width: 5em;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }
      .box1cover{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0.5em;
        width: 3em;
        height: 5em;
        background: #fff;
      }
      .box2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        height: 4em;
        width: 4em;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }
      .wrapper:hover .box1:before, .wrapper:hover .box2{
        border-radius: 30%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="box1">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="box1cover">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="box2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW. first of all, thanks man amazing work, the only problem now is that the gap between the circle and the "rectangle " need to be transparent and this isn't hapening in this solution, image you set body background color to gray, you should see the circle in white and the rectangle  in white but all the little spaces between them should be gray as well ,

Comment: Yes, the transparency is a problem. You could fake it all the time you only use background colors, but its a problem if you use images or gradients. Then I think i would go with a SVG solution.

Comment: Here you have an example of colored background: https://codepen.io/schoien/pen/mdJQqqX

Comment: yes i did that already but i probably will have background with images , can the svg solution work?,  how will i have affects on hover if i switch svg's, i guess it cant work

Comment: You can make one SVG with both states, and just shift background-position on hover. A bit more tricky to animate, but doable. Google  “Svg sprites”